# JS-Script to obfuscate email adresses on website

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone i am looking for a solution to obfuscate email adresses to save from spam-bots. I would really appreciate any help. Its for a page built on HubSpot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318987/hide-email-address-from-bots-keep-mailto

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide email adress with JavaScript](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10572/hide-email-adress-with-javascript)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines